# How to resolve 'Import openai could not be resolved' error (pylance) with pip install command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openai-api, pylance

I feel like I'm asking a dumb question, but I've looked at multiple StackOverflow threads and articles online already but still haven't fixed my problem.

I'm trying to use the OpenAI Python library to train a new model, but even after running multiple variations of the `pip install openai` command, VS Code and Powershell keep returning this:

```
Import "openai" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

and

```
PS C:\Users\achar\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\TaxGPT> openai --version
openai: The term 'openai' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Here are some of the commands I've already tried:

- `pip install openai`
- `pip install openai --user`
- `pip install --upgrade pip`
- `pip install --upgrade pip`
- `pip3 install --upgrade openai --user`
- `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall openai --user`

Thanks for your help, I really do appreciate it!

Comment: Pip installs to the system interpreter, are you using it or a virtual env, or a conda environment?

Comment: I'm running it locally on my own PC.

Comment: What was the output of your `pip install` commands?

Comment: are you using conda? If yes, you can try `conda install -c conda-forge openai`

Comment: The course I'm following had me do: "python -m venv myEnv" and then it wanted me to activate that environment via "source myEnv/bin/activate" but "source" is not defined in my system plus there is no folder bin (there is "scripts" folder and there is a file named activate which has a comment inside the file saying it must be ran by bash but I don't have bash) So all this has me soooo confused... why not just use python that is on the path? Once I removed myEnv folder then the libraries I had installed like openai and numexpr suddenly were available for the code to run. Works now.

Answer (score 4):

Have you set the Python PATH?

In command terminal, run:

```
where python
```

to return the location where python is installed.

In VSCode, open settings.json, which can be quickly accessed using command palette (`CTRL + SHIFT + P`) and typing `settings.json`. Choose the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)`.

Copy the path returned in the terminal.

In the file, add the line:

```json
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": <THE PATH YOU COPIED>,
```

If the path you copied contains backslash, replace them with double backslash or single forward slash.

For example,

```json
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\<YOURUSERNAME>\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python.exe",
```

I highly recommend reading the documentation in VSCode for Python: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/settings-reference

Answer (score 4):

Try this. It worked for me

```
py -m pip install openai --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the tips! I actually had to re-install Python again from https://www.python.org/downloads/, which may have something to do with it not getting added to the PATH correctly.

Answer (score 0):

To use these steps into the terminal in vs code and solve this problem.

- python -m venv venv
- .\venv\Scripts\activate
- pip install openai

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pip install openai --upgrade` to get the latest version. Also, if you are using VScode and virtual env like `conda env`, remember to

1. `conda activate env`
2. Select Corresponding Interpreter